# CKAsset Upload error with Long Lived Operations

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I am receiving an error when the app is trying to upload a CKAsset in a long lived operation once the user has connected back to internet. On re-opening the app the long lived operation returns this error.

> related decl 'e' for CKErrorCode(_nsError: <CKError 0x28352bf60:
> "Invalid Arguments" (12); "Long Lived Operation
> <CKModifyRecordsOperationInfo: 0x104f2c950> may not save a record with
> asset <CKAsset: 0x104ff6760; uploadRank=0,
> path=~/Containers/Data/Application/UUID/Documents/rawContent, UUID= >,
> whose fileURL
> file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/UUID/Documents/rawContent
> is inaccessible">)

The path is accessible by me and is public. What is causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

You may get this error when the url of the file that you want to upload is no longer accessible for the `CKOperation` when you replay / restart it. You can solve this by storing the url as a bookmark when starting the initial operation, like this:

```
 if let data = try? url.bookmarkData(options: .minimalBookmark, includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil, relativeTo: nil) {
     UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "url")
 }
```

Before you setup and restart the long lived operation, restore the bookmark like this:

```
var isStale = false
guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "url"),
      let url = try? URL(resolvingBookmarkData: data, bookmarkDataIsStale: &isStale),
      url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() else {
    return
}
```

Include this in the final completion handler of the restarted operation:

```
url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
```

Comment: The restored long lived operation still has assets with old URLs and says that it cannot be accessed. Should it be cancelled and new one created instead with new urls restored from bookmarks in this case?

Comment: @EugeneBelyakov Yes, in case the url is not accessible in the replay because you haven't stored the bookmark, or restoring the bookmark fails, then the only option is to cancel the operation.